# Enable Disable Checkbox in Asp.net Gridview Based on DropDownList in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

Enable Disable Checkbox in Asp.net Gridview Based on DropDownlist in C#

I have a problem with my C# code.

I need enable or disable checkboxes in asp.net gridview based on DropDownList.

If in the DropDownList no have selected any values the checkboxes in GridView are disabled.

When in the DropDownList have selected a value  the checkboxes in GridView are enabled for the variable selected in the DropDownList.

In the GridView the output is correct when in DropDownList have selected a value, but Checkboxes are always enabled.

I've tried using these solution without success.

Here is my code:

```
   protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox chkSelect = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkSelect");

                if (DDL.SelectedIndex != 0)
                {
                    chkSelect.Enabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

**edit #1**

```
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DDL" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDL_SelectedIndexChanged"
                CssClass="ddl_Class" Enabled="false">
                <asp:ListItem Text="-------" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>                    

                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <center>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBox1_CheckedChanged"
                                AutoPostBack="true" Enabled="false" /></center>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>


protected void DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        CheckBox chkSelect = ((CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("chkSelect"));

        if (DDL.SelectedIndex != 0)
        {
            chkSelect.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    GridViewBind();
}
```

Comment: try to use `dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged` event.First find the check button inside that event and then apply your condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you set check box Enable OR Disable On

```
    protected void DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckBox chkSelect = ((CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("chkSelect"));

            if (DDL.SelectedIndex != 0)
            {
                chkSelect.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. In **edit #1** in my first post new version of my code, the checkboxes now are all disabled.

Comment: @Hamamelis not bind grid second time GridViewBind() remove

Answer (score 0):

Making the string lowercase should help?

```
 Eval("Reason").ToString().ToLower().Equals("hybrid")
```